# Android PowerManager WakeLock – Deprecated

Tags: android

The Android SDK tells me that `PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` and similar constants are deprecated as of API Level 17. It also says that `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` can be used in most situations.

But what if this is not the case? In particular, I want to be able to have the screen dimmed but not shut off entirely. What are other, "better" alternatives – or aren't there simply any?

Comment: I must say, android devs loves deprecating the stuff all over the sdk. They might have some random deprecation generator who tell them on each release which ones to mess with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is currently no better alternative as to actually **use the deprecated WakeLock**.

Actually you have another alternative (but not better). You can use the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` in combination with changing the system brightness manually from inside your activity ([example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html)).

> But what if this is not the case?

I'm having a similar situation in which I need the screen to be **constantly on** from a `Service` (so the Activity.getWindow() is not available). In this case i use the deprecated WakeLock until Android comes up with a new API.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I decided to do, too.