# What should I replace SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK with?

Tags: android, powermanager

I am currently utilizing the below referenced code for a wake lock on an alarm notification activity. However, `SCREEN_DIM_LOCK` has been depreciated. So, what should I be replacing it with?

```
//Instance of wake lock for AlarmActivity
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android Developer documentation specifies that `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` should be replaced with `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. After doing a bit of digging, I turned up this...

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

It should be placed in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: This is a replacement for `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`, not for `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`.

Comment: * @deprecated Most applications should use
     * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON} instead
     * of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform
     * as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.
     */

Answer (score 7):

It can be replaced for `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, as the javadoc says, but this will prevent the screen from dimming - it will remain bright.

This API should not have been deprecated - it is still needed in some cases, such as the "*dim*" case.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15471374/952135).

Comment: Nah, I prevents the screen from turning off in my experience, but does not prevent dimming. I have a device beside me right now; screen dimmed, but did not turn off.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
```

In place of

```
PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
```

Comment: This will prevent the screen from turning off, but won't prevent dimming.